# ASP Net Core Kestrel WebServer loads self-signed root certificate from file but still needs to be in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities Store

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, self-signed, kestrel-http-server, root-certificate

I have an ASP Net Core 6 application with Kestrel Web Server, that requires mTLS between client applications and server.
I created self-signed root and child certificates for the clients, using the New-SelfSignedCertificate cmdlet in powershell.
Here is how the root certificate is explicitly loaded to Kestrel:

```
var rootCertFile ="xxx.pfx";
var rootCertPw = "abc";
X509Certificate2 rootCert = new X509Certificate2( rootCertFile,  rootCertPw);

webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(o =>
{
    o.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(o =>
    {
        o.ServerCertificate = rootCert;
        o.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;
    });
});

webBuilder.UseKestrel(o =>
{
    o.Listen(IPAddress.Parse(myHttpsEndPointIpAddr), myHttpsEndPointPort,
        listenOptions =>
        {
            listenOptions.UseHttps();
        });
    o.Listen(IPAddress.Parse(myHttpEndPointIpAddr), myHttpEndPointPort);
});
```

If some client (for instance curl or postman) calls (using a child certificate signed by the root) some https endpoint, the client gets an error and the call is rejected, if the root certificate is not present in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities Certificate Store of the Local machine. Here is the error that the client sees:

```
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* OpenSSL SSL_read: error:0A000418:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert unknown ca, errno 0
* Failed receiving HTTP2 data
* OpenSSL SSL_write: SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN, errno 0
* Failed sending HTTP2 data
```

As soon as the root certificate is added to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities Certificate Store of the Local machine, the rest api call succeeds.
Why does the root self-signed certificate need to be installed into Trusted Root Certification Authorities Certificate Store, if Kestrel directly loads the root certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68146868/oncertificatevalidated-not-running-self-signed-certificate-client-authenticati) we can see there are two ways `Recognizing client certificates` .

> Firstly, the server was not recognizing the self-signed client
> certificates as valid certificates. This can be solved by either 1.
> adding all of the client certificates (or a root CA that signs them
> all) to the trusted certificate store of the operating system or 2.
> adding a ClientCertificateValidation callback to kestrel to determine
> whether or not a certificate is accepted or rejected.

From [Install in the trusted root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0#install-in-the-trusted-root)

> The root certificate needs to be trusted on your host system. A root
> certificate which was not created by a certificate authority won't be
> trusted by default. For information on how to trust the root
> certificate on Windows, see this question.

This is an example : [Correct way of loading SSL certificate signed by Intermediate CA in Kestrel .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56463889/correct-way-of-loading-ssl-certificate-signed-by-intermediate-ca-in-kestrel-net)

Read [Installing the trusted root certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/sdn/articles/installing-the-trusted-root-certificate) and [Trusted Root Certification Authorities Certificate Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/trusted-root-certification-authorities-certificate-store) to know more .

Comment: Thanks for the very useful links. Is there any possibility to log on ASP NET Core / Kestrel side what exactly happens during certificate validation, especially when the client certificates are rejected?

Comment: @RickyTad Do  you mean this: [custom validator to see what is going on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56346555/net-core-adding-client-certificate-to-post-to-kestrel-rest-api-on-linux-fails-s) ?

Comment: Thanks again for the link, it helped. Is it possible to get more details than the SslPolicyErrors enum value? What about the Kestrel ListenOptions "UseConnectionLogging" method, what details does it log and where?